# Worklight 6.2.0.1 issue with xCode 7.3.1 on iOS9+

Tags: xcode, ibm-mobilefirst

I have two applications developed on WL 6.2.0.1. And I was building my iOS projects using xCode 6.3.1 as I wasn't facing any issues on iOS (All OS versions)

When I upgraded my xCode to 7.3.1. all my iOS projects that are running on iPhone/iPad with iOS9+ starts to fail and it not even connecting to my WL server anymore.

Any invocation I make it failed and I see no logs on the server, meaning it is not even reaching it.

If I tested the same build that is done on xCode 7.3.1 but with iOS8 it works.

When I revert back my xCode update as I have a time machine, all start working again on All OS versions.

Is there a known issue with WL 6.2.0.1 with new xCode? I have been searching and couldn't find anything about this.

Server version: 6.2.0.01.20141013-1735

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with Xcode 7 and iOS 9, Apple now requires ATS (Application Transport Security) by enabling TLS 1.2 on the server and working with HTTPS on the client. That is why all your requests are failing - because the client & server are misconfigured.

During development, you can disable ATS. See here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/09/09/ats-and-bitcode-in-ios9/

For production-time, you'll want to read this: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/09/07/preparing-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-server-app-transport-security-ios-9/

Comment: Thank you Idan, do those links/configuration applies on WL 6.2.0.1? or they are restrict to MFP?

Comment: They are due to iOS, so they apply to any Worklight version you use. Make sure to update to the latest iFix for iOS 9 support.